# HTML теги выводятся как текст, нужно чтобы они выводились именно как HTML сущности

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! По каким то причинам php выводит html разметку, как обычный текст. А мне нужно чтобы html выводился именно как html, а не как простой текст. Вопрос такой. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не используйте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php при выводе информации. P.S. И в результате получите кучу уязвимостей на сайте ;)

Comment: просто htmlspecialchars судя по всему используется где то в ядре CMS. Я же не буду ядро править. Мне нужно какой нить решение которое отменит htmlspecialchars.  И выведет нормальный html

Comment: Ну есть общее решение. Это всякие разные bbcodes, шот-коды, Markdown разметка.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Как выводит, где выводит, откуда он берет эту разметку. Наугад на вопрос ответить нельзя, и сам по себе PHP ничего с разметкой просто-так делать не будет.

Comment: А какую CMS используете ?

Answer (score -1):

Возможно Вам поможет данная функция http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php.
Указанная функция преобразует такие символы как "<" и ">" в "<" и ">" соответственно. Работает также и с кавычками, одинарными и двойными.

Comment: А что там в ссылке? Не могли бы вы описать.

Comment: Под отвветом есть кнопка править. Дополните ответ, а комментарий потом удалите.